# which command is linux's netview?

Tags: command-line, networking, windows

In windows, I can use netview to see all the computers on the LAN network, but what's the corresponding command on linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes you can.

open your terminal and type as  `who -a` . that will list all information .

else you can use `nmap` also . great network tool.

you can get it by `sudo apt-get install nmap`

if you assume you IP starts from

192.168.1.1 then you can list all Computers connected with the LAN  with this command

```
nmap 192.168.1.1-255
```

The above command will scan from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255 IP's and list you which is up and which is down .

Comment: Or use Zenmap if you want a graphical interface for nmap

Answer (score 3):

You can type

> arp -a

commandin terminal to see computers on Lan.

Comment: Note that `arp` shows the IPs that the computer has contacted from cache so it doesn't list all devices on the network. One should use a ping loop to contact all the hosts first then use `arp`.

Answer (score 1):

`net view` on Windows is used for [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory). You can emulate this with [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29).

Use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba
```

This will install `net` commands that you can use to join the Windows domain, such as:

```
$ net help join
Usage:
net rpc join -U <username>[%%password] <type>
  Join a domain
    username    Name of the admin user    password  Password of the admin user, will prompt if not specified
    type    Can be one of the following:
        MEMBER  Join as member server (default)
        BDC Join as BDC
        PDC Join as PDC
```

You can also use `arp-scan`, [found here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/arp-scan.1.html), if you're only looking to discover hosts on the network.